# Can I get the Silverlight mediaplayer to play .Vox files?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I need to play .vox files on my web page.  Does anyone have any tips on how to play .vox files using the Silverlight Mediaplayer control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight will only play VC-1 encoded content right now.  You can see the supported formats/containers here: [Supported Audio and Video Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It won't play VOX files. Convert it to MP3 and it should play.